# Clicking this button in VB?

Tags: html, vb.net, click, invoke

I need to click a specific button, but I cant figure out how...
Heres the code for the button from the webpage:

```
<input type="image" src="images/search2.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/search2hi.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/search2.png'" onclick="showCarrier(document.getElementById('small').value, document.getElementById('large').value);return false"/>
```

How do I click this button?
I've already tried

```
For Each element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("image")
    element.InvokeMember("click")
Next
```

But it clicks an ad instead. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably clicking the only first link with your code as your browser will navigate away from the page on the first click. 
You could try the following (not tested):

```
For Each element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("image")
  dim src as String = element.GetAttribute("src")

  If src isnot nothing andalso sec.EndsWith("images/search2.png") Then
    element.InvokeMember("click")
  end if
Next
```

It will search the element identified by the image it displays.

Comment: didn't work as in "the same button gets clicked" or "no button is clicked"?